# Excel column manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to find cell named North and take everything below it
I know that we can easily locate this using loc and iloc, but in my case it may vary every time my app opens new excel file. I tried using str.contains

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `iloc` and `idxmax`:

```
df.iloc[df.eq('North').any(1).idxmax():]
```

Comment: it was a great answer, however it won't always be below Tunnel Manager Information. Sorry maybe I wasn't clear about that